# WCF Test Client - Any way to save the services/settings to a file to reload easily later?

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration, wcftestclient

The WCF Test Client is a really powerful tool. I can avoid creating a new console app to test my services. However, what is annoying is that I can't seem to save the services/config I add to the client. If I close it and open it again it starts fresh.

Any way to save an "instance" of the WCF Test Client... kind of like how FxCop let's you scan your binaries and save that setting to an FxCop file?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't think there's any such feature in the WCF Test Client.

Comment: The WCF Test Client is a very simple tool for simple testing - if you need more elaborate testing of web services, you should check out [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) - it can do a lot more (and store profiles/parameters etc. to files)

Comment: @marc_s in my experience SoapUI lacks capabilities around authentication modes (it says it does but they simply don't work for our services). I always fall back to WcfStorm but it can't save and load reliably either so there just doesn't seem to be a decent product that covers all bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of the test client will remember the last few URLs you've used. Is that not enough?

[image]

Comment: Not when I'm wanting to put the Test Client on our csv with presaved settings so other developers can easily open a preconfigured WCF Test Client. Guess not though.

Comment: Why not just write a batch file that calls the URLs: `wcfTestClient.exe http://localhost/MyService.svc http://localhost/MyOtherService.svc`  This will start the WCF UI, but auto-add the nominated URLs.

Comment: @myermian: that's a job for a tool like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) - WCF Test Client isn't made for this kind of task...

Answer (score 0):

If the config file is changed the settings are automatically stored (in case the "Always Regenerate Config When Launching Services" option is disabled).

You can see the details in [this section](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe.md#location-of-files-generated-by-the-test-client) of the Wcf Test Client documentation.